# File Sharing with Active Directory login not working

Tags: file-sharing, active-directory

I've set up macOS Sierra (10.12.6) machine and it binds to AD (Win2012R2).
It works with SSH and VNC login without any problem, but not work with File Sharing.

Connect to mac server as smb://macserver then user authentication prompt popup, but cannot login with AD user account... Auth with mac server's local account works, I can mount file share.

Is there any special setting for it?　Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Now fixed, computername should be less than 15 characters but it was 16. Changed to fewer letters then it works.